# i18n prints that key instead of the value

Tags: javascript, typescript, internationalization

I'm trying to set up `i18n`.

I created a JSON file to store the key-value, but the `i18n` prints the key instead of the value.

For example:

JSON file:

```
{
"hi": "Welcome {{name}}"
}
```

The code:

```
__({ phrase: 'hi', locale: 'en' }, { name: 'Marcus' });
```

It prints `hi` instead of `Welcome Marcus`.

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some wrong configuration on your local

- check the directory config

```
const i18n = new I18n({
  locales: ['en', 'de'], // <-- should have these "<locale-name>.json" file according to your support locales. Eg: en.json, de.json.
  directory: path.join(__dirname, 'locales') // <-- this
})
```

- check the file name should be: `en.json` located inside `locales` directory

From your info above I make a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-4ue5wc